# User Login Tutorial

Tags: html, authentication

I want to create a primitive HTML login form with just the basics ( username, password). However, I am having a hard
time finding beginner tutorials. I appreciate it if anyone can point me to some resources. I only
have a smattering of HTML, PHP, SQL, and PHP.

Comment: What makes you think we're going to do even better?

Comment: The basics are where you need to start if you're having a hard time with the basics.

Comment: @John For someone with almost 40,000 reputation points you probably know more than I do (or spend more time in front of computer than I do).

Comment: @Kai That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: You will find that more help will come to you if you post code to show you have tried. Ideally not enormous full scripts, but just where you are having problems. SO is a QA forum where we give advise or clarification on issues, not exactly things so broad as - say - how do you code in php. Surely you have tried something and surely you got stuck somewhere. That would be the right thing to post. Otherwise you may get snide remarks or barely helpful links. Or exactly what you're looking for - who knows. But narrower is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic register and login series with intermediate security. It uses PHP & MySQL. This should help.

[Register & Login Series](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECE134D877783367C7)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

You will need some server side language to actually process html form, php could be good choice.

Comment: Ewww, bad 'tutorial' link. SQL injections abound.